# The namespace name 'SyntaxTree' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, namespaces, visual-studio-2019

I have am developing in Unity 2019.2.3f1. I am trying to write a script that can [Customize project files created by VSTU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/customize-project-files-created-by-vstu?view=vs-2019). In case the link ever gets removed, I have included a script very similar to the one from the link.

```
#if ENABLE_VSTU
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class ProjectFileHook
{
    private class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    static ProjectFileHook()
    {
        ProjectFilesGenerator.ProjectFileGeneration += (string name, string content) =>
        {
            // parse the document and make some changes
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(content);
            document.Root?.Add(new XComment("FIX ME"));

            // save the changes using the Utf8StringWriter
            Utf8StringWriter str = new Utf8StringWriter();
            document.Save(str);

            return str.ToString();
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

The issue is, `using SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge;` fails to compile due to the error `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SyntaxTree' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

I have checked both Unity and Visual Studio that the Visual Studio Tools for Unity are installed and enabled.

[image]

Why is the code failing to compile? Am I missing something that is preventing it from compiling?

Comment: According to https://forum.unity.com/threads/syntaxtree-missing-reference.384423/ you just need to add the visual studio code editor package... as I cant use asset store of package manager through corporate firewalls I cant test it for you

Comment: @BugFinder I'm afraid this solution did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone else has this issue.

This issue was being caused by the scripts position. The script has to be under the `Editor` folder, otherwise the script won't work as expected.

Credits to [therealjohn](https://github.com/therealjohn) for pointing it out [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4248#issuecomment-547998056).